# Code parses only first <div></div> child

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have 3 children `<div></div>` in the main `<div class="RecentTrades"></div>` node. But my code parses only the first children (which are the headers i.e. Date, Time, etc). While debugging, first round was okay (cols to cols8 appear to have values), but when the code `for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)` ran for second round, cols to cols8 became `null`. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

`<div></div>`:

```
<div class="RecentTrades">
    <div class="TradesRow TradesHeader">
        <div class="TradesDate">Date</div>
        <div class="TradesTime">Time</div>
        <div class="TradesPrice">Trade Prc</div>
        <div class="TradesVolume">Volume</div>
        <div class="TradesBuySell">Buy/Sell</div>
        <div class="TradesBid">Bid</div>
        <div class="TradesAsk">Ask</div>
        <div class="TradesValue">Value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="TradesRow TradesBG_G" style="color:#ff0000;">
        <div class="TradesDate">08-Jan-14</div>
        <div class="TradesTime">17:05:00</div>
        <div class="TradesPrice">83.80</div>
        <div class="TradesVolume">1,970,861</div>
        <div class="TradesBuySell">Sell*&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="TradesBid">83.85</div>
        <div class="TradesAsk">83.88</div>
        <div class="TradesValue">1.652<strong>M</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="TradesRow TradesBG_W" style="color:#ff0000;">
        <div class="TradesDate">07-Jan-14</div>
        <div class="TradesTime">16:30:11</div>
        <div class="TradesPrice">80.739</div>
        <div class="TradesVolume">40,000</div>
        <div class="TradesBuySell">Sell*&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="TradesBid">83.85</div>
        <div class="TradesAsk">83.88</div>
        <div class="TradesValue">32.30<strong>k</strong></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
// Load HTML
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileName);
// Get specific node in the document
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='RecentTrades']"); 

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"..\..\bin\Debug\ModifiedPages\" + "RecentShareTrades.txt", FileMode.Append))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
      // Iterate all rows in the relevant div
      HtmlNodeCollection rows = node.SelectNodes(".//div");
      for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
      {
           // Iterate all columns in this row
           HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesDate']");
           HtmlNodeCollection cols2 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesTime']");
           HtmlNodeCollection cols3 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesPrice']");
           HtmlNodeCollection cols4 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesVolume']");
           HtmlNodeCollection cols5 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesBuySell']");
           HtmlNodeCollection cols6 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesBid']");
           HtmlNodeCollection cols7 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesAsk']");
           HtmlNodeCollection cols8 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesValue']");

           for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; ++j)
           // Get the value of the column and print it
           sw.WriteLine(cols[j].InnerText + "," + cols2[j].InnerText + "," + cols3[j].InnerText + "," + cols4[j].InnerText.Replace(",", "") + "," + cols5[j].InnerText + "," + cols6[j].InnerText + "," + cols7[j].InnerText + "," + cols8[j].InnerText + "," + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
       }
       sw.Flush();
       sw.Close();
       fs.Close();
 }
```

Comment: You may want to read some intro to XPath (or even first part of the specification - http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates)... I'm not sure why you are using `//` (all nodes matching criteria) everywhere - likely picking up way more nodes than you need (and much less effective than explicit path like `"./div/div/dvi[@class='TradesAsk']"`

Comment: Hi Alexei, I tried using such way `"./div/div/div[@class='TradesAsk']"`but it doesn't work too. I was playing around with the `.` and `/` but no hope.

Comment: The path was just random sample of how one would look like, sorry for too realistic sample. Explicit paths are faster and easier to understand later (since you will not grab nodes from all over the tree).

Comment: Yes, I understand it's just a sample, thank you for helping me and no need for sorry. :) Just a question, `<div class="TradesRow TradesHeader">`, `<div class="TradesRow TradesBG_G" style="color:#ff0000;">`, `<div class="TradesRow TradesBG_W" style="color:#ff0000;">`, they all have `class=TradesRow`. How would I write this line `HtmlNodeCollection rows = node.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesRow']");` if I want it to detect only the first `class` i.e. `class="TradesRow`? It's okay if you're not answering it. Thank you.